# VBA: SolverAdd Ignorning Constraints

Tags: vba, excel, solver

I'm trying to set up solver for each run of a macro but it seems to be ignoring some of the constraints but not all of them for some reason.

```
SolverReset
SolverOk SetCell:="$N$15", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=Range("i3", Range("i3").End(xlDown)), _
Engine:=3, EngineDesc:="Evolutionary"
SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("k3", Range("k3").End(xlDown)), Relation:=1, FormulaText:="1"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$P$12:$P$13", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$R$12:$R$13"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$P$12:$P$13", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="$N$12:$N$13"
SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("n3", Range("n3").End(xlDown)), Relation:=2, FormulaText:="1"
SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("i3", Range("i3").End(xlDown)), Relation:=5, FormulaText:="binary"
SolverSolve
```

It is only ignoring the constraints for the ranges Range("n3", Range("n3").End(xlDown)) and Range("k3", Range("k3").End(xlDown))

Any help would be appreciated.

thanks!

Comment: How many cells in the ignored ranges? I think there are some limits on the version of solver included in excel...   http://www.solver.com/suppstdsizelim2.htm

Comment: There might be 20 cells in each ignored range and that shouldn't be the issue because I can solve it if I set it up manually, and the max 200 variables applies to changing cells only, of which I have about 20, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From XL Help:

"Relation   Required Integer. The arithmetic relationship between the left and right sides of the constraint. If you choose *4 or 5*, CellRef must refer to adjustable (changing) cells, and *FormulaText should not be specified*."

Your last range has relation=5, so you can't include FormulaText.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and FormulaText for range with relation=5 was not a problem, but problem was FormulaText="1". Every SolverAdd which had FormulaText="1" was ignored in solver.
Solution for me was just to add "1" in one cell (e.g E9) and set FormulaText="$E$9".
There is probably better solution, but this was fine for me...

Answer (score 1):

There is probably better solution, but this Works fine for me :

```
SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("k3", Range("k3").End(xlDown)), Relation:=1, FormulaText:="SUM(1)"
```

just replace "1" with "SUM(1)" .